# cleaner way to update a state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The use case of my application is. The data should be fetched from the server and show those data in form so that user can update the form with the preloaded data. The form should be controlled one instead of uncontrolled. For this use case what I did is I fetched the data from server inside `componentDidMount` lifecycle which is the preferred one. And in `componentWillReceiveProps` I checked if there is data, if there is then update local react state with the data that has come from server. Now that I have data in the react local state, I then developed a form and fill those data in the value attribute with onChange event handler. This is working but I am in learning phase I need to understand from the expert how would you handle such use case if you have to. Can anyone help me to code better way, please? I don't see huge react community in codereview. If i need to close this question, Please I will but please be kind. I reckon, learning should not have any barrier. This is my View.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  requestCloudinary: cloudinary => dispatch(cloudinaryRequest(cloudinary)),
  loadCloudinary: () => dispatch(fetchCloudinary())
});

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  cloudinaryService: selectCloudinary()
});

class Cloudinary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cloudinary: {
        _id: "",
        cloudinary_cloud_name: "",
        cloudinary_api_key: "",
        cloudinary_api_secret: ""
      },
      errors: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadCloudinary();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevProps) {
    const { cloudinaryService } = nextProps;
    if (cloudinaryService.size) {
      cloudinaryService
        .entrySeq()
        .map(([key, value]) => {
          this.setState(state => ({
            cloudinary: { ...state.cloudinary, [key]: value }
          }));
        })
        .toArray();
    }
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    this.setState(
      {
        cloudinary: {
          ...this.state.cloudinary,
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
      },
      () => {
        this.validateField([fieldName]);
      }
    );
  };

  handleBlur = event => {
    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    this.validateField([fieldName]);
  };

  validateField = validate => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    let hasError = false;
    validate.forEach(field => {
      if (this.state.cloudinary[field].length === 0) {
        hasError = true;
        errors[field] = `${field} cannot be empty`;
      } else {
        errors[field] = "";
      }
    });
    this.setState({ errors });
    return !hasError;
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (
      this.validateField([
        "cloudinary_cloud_name",
        "cloudinary_api_key",
        "cloudinary_api_secret"
      ])
    ) {
      this.props.requestCloudinary(this.state.cloudinary);
      console.log("event", event.target);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { cloudinary, errors } = this.state;
    const { cloudinaryService } = this.props;
    console.log("cloudinaryService", cloudinaryService);
    let message;
    if (typeof cloudinaryService === "string") {
      message = <div>{cloudinaryService}</div>;
    }
    if (cloudinaryService.size === 0) {
      return (
        <div className="earth-spinning">
          <img src={Spinner} alt="spinner" style={{ margin: "0 auto" }} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="container cloudinary">
        <Notification>
          {message && message}
        </Notification>
        <h1>Cloudinary Settings</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <TextFieldGroup
            id="formControlsText"
            name="cloudinary_cloud_name"
            type="text"
            value={cloudinary.cloudinary_cloud_name}
            label="Cloud Name"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onBlur={this.handleBlur}
            error={errors.cloudinary_cloud_name}
            required
          />
          <TextFieldGroup
            id="formControlsText"
            name="cloudinary_api_key"
            type="text"
            value={cloudinary.cloudinary_api_key}
            label="API Key"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onBlur={this.handleBlur}
            error={errors.cloudinary_api_key}
            required
          />
          <TextFieldGroup
            id="formControlsText"
            name="cloudinary_api_secret"
            type="text"
            value={cloudinary.cloudinary_api_secret}
            label="API Secret"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            onBlur={this.handleBlur}
            error={errors.cloudinary_api_secret}
            required
          />
          <button className="btn btn-default">Save changes</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Cloudinary);
```

Comment: IMHO, at least the common way to do this is by using Redux, you'll find a ton of tutorials on Redux and React.

Comment: I am doing using redux. You can see mapStateToProps has been used. Since I want controlled form so I am updating the local state to preload the data as it is for update form. For update form, the data has to be shown in the input box in advance. So I am doing the above way.